# Why do we say a real line is an open set, but the complex plane is not an open set?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Why do we say a real line is an open set, but the complex plane is not an open set?

I don't understand that? I'm fully confused between these differences?

Comment: What? The complex line is an open set in the usual topology on the complex plane, just as the real line is open in the usual topology on the real line. In general, if $X$ is a topological space, we require $X$ to be open.

Comment: *We* do not say that.

Comment: The closest interpretation is that the real line is not open in the plane, which is true.

Comment: Who have you heard say that/where have you seen that said?

Answer (score 8):

The key is that we never say "$X$ is open." [*] Rather, we say, "$X$ is an open subset of the topological space $Y$." It does not make sense to talk about a set being open in and of itself.

All sets are "open" as subsets of themselves. This is because we want every point to be in *some* open set, and since we also want the union of open sets, we want the whole set to be open.

[*] Okay. sometimes we just say "$X$ is open," but in those cases, there is an implicit $Y$ that is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

What topology you're talking about?
Actually if you think of the real line as the line $y=0$ in the complex plane then the real line will not remain open anymore, because it can't contain any open balls of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (in this case 2-dimmensional discs). This all depends on which topology you're talking about. However, Both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are open (and also closed) with their own usual topologies and this is one of the axioms of topology using open sets.

Comment: I mildly object to the term "will not remain open anymore..." I think that gives the wrong impression.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Well, maybe you're right. What would be your suggestion to choose a better term to reword my phrase?

Comment: Not sure how to give the right impression, just thing "remains" and "anymore" gives a weird impression - like the openness of $\mathbb R$ is changing, when the property of "openness" is really a property of a set in relation to a space, not a property of the set alone.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is open in itself, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not open as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Neal: Sure, that is the point of my explanation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, I see what you mean. But I can't think of any other way to reword it currently. But the fact that the property of openness can change, means that it isn't an absolute and intrinsic property of the set, but it is relative and is in relation to a space.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, it was a mild complaint. Not sure how I'd rephrase it.

Comment: @some1.new4u Right, that's just how I'd phrase what you're saying.

Comment: The temporal terminology "remain" and "anymore" can be confusing, but I think it would be OK if similar temporal terminology is used for the ambient space:  "If you change your point of view to think of subspaces of $\mathbb C$ where you were previously thinking of subspaces of $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb R$ will not remain open any more."

Answer (score 2):

The real line is an open set in itself because it has no boundary points and each of its points is an interior point, that is in regard to the space of the real numbers. However, if we look at any line in the complex plane, we look at it as a subset of the complex space and that is a different matter, as Thomas points out: 'the property of openness is a property of a set in relation to a space, not a property of the set alone.' In relation to the complex space, a line S consists of boundary points only, because the neighborhoods of each point on the line will all have some points in S (i.e. the neighboring points on the line) as well as points which are not in S (i.e other neighboring points not on the line). So a line in the complex space is a set which has no interior points but only boundary points. That being said, it contains all of its boundary points and, therefore, the set (i.e. the line in the complex space) is to be considered as a closed set. I can refer here to the solutions to exercises 1, 2 and 3 in section 10 of Brown and Churchill's 'Complex variables and applications' (7th edition) where the example (d), i.e. the example of a line, is NOT mentioned as a set that is 'neither open nor closed'. It is also NOT 'both open and closed'. A line is, quite simply, a closed set - as part of the complex space that is. Sorry for being lengthy but it's because of the definitions involved.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you reading this? In its usual topology, the complex plane is an open set.

As T. Bongers points out in a comment, requiring an entire space to be open in itself is built into the very axioms of topology.

Answer (score 1):

Both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are metric spaces, with metric given by
$$
d(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert.
$$
The topology induced by a metric $d$ on a space $X$ is such that a set $A\subseteq X$ is open if and only if for each $x\in A$, there is a small "ball" around $x$ which is contained in $A$: that is, there is some number $\epsilon>0$ such that $\{z\in X\mid d(x,z)<\epsilon\}\subseteq A$.

So, both the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ are open sets, when imbued with the metric topology induced by their usual metrics.

As a point of fact: part of the definition of a topology on a set $X$ is that we must consider $X$ itself as an open set.